# dplyr replace NAs in a new column with a function of the good values

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Mininal example: A small dataframe with 6 rows and two columns of responses to questions along with a column of ID's

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2), "C"),
                 Q1 = sample(0:5, 10, replace=T),
                 Q2 = sample(0:3, 10, replace=T)
                )
```

I need to create a new dataframe with the standard deviations of Q1 and Q2 by ID, and so write

```
questions <- c("Q1", "Q2")
df_sigma <- df %>%
              group_by(ID) %>%
                summarize(across(all_of(questions), 
                           .fns = sd, 
                           .names = paste0("Sigma_", "{.col}")))
```

which gives me

```
df_sigma
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    Sigma_Q1 Sigma_Q2
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A         1.73    0.577
2 B         2.12    1.41 
3 C        NA      NA
```

The standard deviation of Q1 and Q2 for user C is NA, as it should be - user C has only one entry. How can I replace the NAs in each column with the mean or the median of all the other values in the same column, so that, for example, df_sigma[3, "Sigma_Q1"] = median(df_sigma[1, "Sigma_Q1"], df_sigma[2, "Sigma_Q1"]) and similarly for Sigma_Q2?  In general, there will be multiple questions and quite a few NAs that are sprinkled randomly among the columns.

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: Check your example - it's not reproducible at the moment as ``df``` has different number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df_sigma2 <- df_sigma %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("Sigma"),
        ~ replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```